# Issue to open browser on specified site with specified input on click button

Tags: android

if user click on it i want to open the browser on
http://www.dtcsearch.com/ and on this site in bar search i want to auto-insert the value of string S of my program.
at example:
if s="ciao"
and the user click on button i want to open http://www.dtcsearch.com/  with written in search ciao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a browser you can simply launch an activity as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.dtcsearch.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

But to fill in the search box on the web-page, you need to modify your web-page too to incorporate/support this requirement. For example, you need to put your search string in the URL and then modify your web page to read the url contents via **GET** method and fill in the provided search string in the textbox.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse("http://www.dtcsearch.com/?s=hello"));
startActivity(i);
```

and in webpage (suppose its written in **PHP**)

```
$strSearch = $_GET["s"];  //should return 'hello'
```

Finally, use `$strSearch` to fill in the search textbox on webpage.